# What is the word or idiom for a system which is not well maintained and has become useless?

Tags: idioms, formality

In Finnish we say *rämettyä*, where *räme* is a kind of swamp or marsh, so it literally means *become a swamp*. I guess that is understandable English, but it sounds quite informal. Especially, I am looking for a term for technical system.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "not well maintained" and "has become useless".  Buggy?   Does not suit present needs?

Comment: If it's software you could say that it suffered from code rot. It happens when the computing environment changes and the old code, which hasn't been maintained for a while, doesn't even compile.

Comment: Deprecated? Although I think this implies it has been superseded by a newer version. Also this is more of a software term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many adjectives which mean "deteriorated due to disuse".

Probably the closest English equivalent to your "swamp" is *gone to seed*¹, but as you say that's not very formal.

More formal, or high-register, words include:

- *derelict*
- *dilapidated*
- *ramshackle*
- *neglected*

However, these are generic descriptors and not specific to any technical field (excepting *derelict*, which has a specific technical meaning in nautical jargon).

¹ <sub>A more colorful idiom is *gone to rack and ruin*.</sub>

Comment: +1 for *dilapidation*. Indeed in UK property and tenancy law, it has a [specific meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilapidation) (usually in the plural) of the material defects that have occurred *due to* neglect or lack of maintenance by the person responsible (e.g. a tenant).

Answer (score 2):

One possible technical term for an unmaintained system is **abandonware**.

> Abandonware is a product, typically software, ignored by its owner and manufacturer, and for which no product support is available.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abandonware

Comment: That is a funny word!

Comment: Yep, and it's quite well-known in the tech world.

Comment: Good word, but this time I did not mean discontinued or product, but an installed system, like process automation, which starts behaving erroneously when not maintained. I was not clear enough in the question.